# Installing from composer not getting main.css and main.js files

Tags: composer

I am facing a difficulties while trying to install the fullcalendar via composer (composer.phar require "bower-asset/fullcalendar"), it is not pulling the **main.css** and **main.js** files. So, I have to do this manually by downloading the files from [here](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/initialize-globals).

Just wanted to confirm is this a bug or feature?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since Yii 2.0.13 both Basic and Advanced application templates are pre-configured to use asset-packagist.

As you are using the Yii2 Framework and you want to use composer to install the fullcalendar plugin and the needed assets, this should be the recommended procedure:

1. (optional) create a basic project template: `composer create-project --prefer-dist yiisoft/yii2-app-basic fullcalendar-yii-basic`
2. change your working directory to the root directory of your project: `cd fullcalendar-yii-basic`
3. install the fullcalendar bundle using asset-packagist (already configured when using a Yii 2 project template): `composer require npm-asset/fullcalendar`

Source:

- https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/structure-assets#bower-npm-assets

You will find the files main.css and main.js in folder `vendor/npm-asset/fullcalendar`.

To use them in Yii you should create an AssetBundle like this (put it in folder assets):

```
<?php

namespace app\assets;

use yii\web\AssetBundle;

/**
 * Fullcalendar asset bundle.
 */
class FullcalendarAsset extends AssetBundle
{
    public $sourcePath = '@npm/fullcalendar';
    public $css = [
        YII_ENV_DEV ? 'main.css' : 'main.min.css'
    ];
    public $js = [
        YII_ENV_DEV ? 'main.js' : 'main.min.js',
        YII_ENV_DEV ? 'locales-all.js' : 'locales-all.min.js'
    ];
}
```

In your view you have to register that AssetBundle:

```
<?php

/* @var $this yii\web\View */

use app\assets\FullcalendarAsset;
FullcalendarAsset::register($this);

$this->title = 'My Yii Application';
```

Comment: I am using Yii2 framework and to add the libraries/plugins for my web application, using composer so using composer command to install fullcalendar library. 
The question is, I am not getting main js and css file while using composer to install fullcalendar library.

Comment: Please have a look at my updated answer. :)

Comment: Which version of composer are you using? Please check with `composer --version`

Comment: Thanks composer require npm-asset/fullcalendar is pulling the main js and css files but composer require "bower-asset/fullcalendar is not pulling.

Thanks for your support. I will use npm-asset/fullcalendar for now.

Comment: I'm glad I was able to help! :)